# Date Range Search on a collection of child elements in Lucene document

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have a Lucene index on documents that have associated child objects.  My documents (Widgets) have data that can be thought of like this:

```
Name = "Cool Widget"
Todo = { Description = "Invent", Due = "1/18/2014" }
Todo = { Description = "Manufacture", Due = "2/17/2014" }
```

I would like to be able to be able search for Widgets that have Todos with a specific Description in a given date range.  (e.g. "Invent" Todos due within the next week)

How can I build the Lucene index and query to do this?

Is this possible with just a Lucene index on Widgets, or do I have to build two indexes - one for Widgets and one for Todos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible using [block join](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html). Has some limitations but should work for your use case.

Of course you can also do this on your own (by running several queries, or creating a SearchComponent) in a single index (you don't need to have one 'sort' of docs in an index, you can mix widgets and todos just fine), but I would use block join.

Comment: I'll give block join a try, it looks promising.  Thanks.

Comment: Ack, I'm in .Net and it looks like Lucene.Net has not been updated since Lucene v3.03 and block join was introduced in v3.4.  I searched a bit for SearchComponent - is that specific to Solr?

Comment: yes that is Solr specific. I guess your can always look at how block join was implemented and try to port it to Lucene.Net as well as you can...